# is comparison on various objects in python

Tags: python

When I do the `is` comparison on a list is acts differently than on a number or string. For example:

```
>>> a=[1,2,3] # id = 4344829768
>>> b=[1,2,3] # id = 4344829960
>>> a is b
False

>>> c=1 # id = 4304849280
>>> d=1
>>> c is d
True
```

Why is this so?

Comment: If you had done `id(d)`, you would have answered your question

Comment: @smac89 -- right, why doesn't the list have the same memory address if the elements are all the same?

Comment: The content of the list does not define its memory address. I think you may be confusing memory address with hash value of an object. The two lists may store the same values, but they are different lists because you created them separately. If you did `b = a`, then you would have got `true`.